# How to use multiple themes in Sitecore SXA?

Tags: sxa, multisite

We already have a theme per site. We would like to create a common/shared theme and configure for few SXA sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create it like you normally do.

Then if you want to have it available on other sites add it to `Compatilbe themes` field (notice that I added **Wireframe** which is default theme)

[image]

#### Optional

If this will be common theme it would be good to store theme classes in a single place (if there will be any, I assume there will be some).

Then you might want to create base site for that, here are details.

https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/share-data-sources-and-presentation-using-the-multisite-feature.html

Comment: @Alan-Thank you for your response. After adding a new theme in Compatible themes, how to use/refer this new theme along with existing theme for a site (without creating a base site)

Comment: @ss0326 I am not sure if I understand. The thing I described is for configuring compatible themes for a site. If you want to assign/change a theme for a site you do this on `Page Designs` item (field `Theme` in `Styling` section).
Here is how you can do it in EE (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/assign-a-theme.html)

Comment: We have some custom components in Site A and those components scripts and styles are in Site A theme. Now we would like to reuse those components in Site B and C so we would like to move the styles and scripts to Generic/Basic theme. But don't know how to use both Site specific theme as well as Generic/Basic theme in all sites

Comment: @ss0326 This is different questions. Please read article that I linked: `By default, adding a shared site implies that the following presentation items can be shared from that site: page designs, partial designs, rendering variants, styles, and themes.` This pretty much gives you what you want. You just have to create a base site, mark it as shared, move styles there from Site A and be able to use them in SiteA, SiteB. Themes are stored in media library and I already described how to reuse them.

Comment: @Allan-Thank you for your reply. Your answer is one way to handle the common/shared themes. I fixed my issue by creating a base theme and inherited in my other sites.